# Is there an easy alternative to DistinctCount by using an ActivePivot Post processor

Tags: mdx, activepivot

I have a slow MDX query that does the following:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.DistinctCode as 'DistinctCount({[CODE].Children})'
SELECT 
NON EMPTY Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[DATE].[ALL].[AllMember]})}) ON ROWS,
NON EMPTY Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[SYSTEM].[ALL].[AllMember]})}) ON COLUMNS
FROM [CUBE]
WHERE ([Measures].[DistinctCode])
```

How could I write a post processed measure in ActivePivot that returns the same as my Distinct Count calculated member? I imagine this would be a lot faster?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a "distinct count" measure with ActivePivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412641/how-can-i-create-a-distinct-count-measure-with-activepivot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the LeafCountPostProcessor that ships out of the box in the open-source activepivot-ext artifact?

```
com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.postprocessing.impl.LeafCountPostProcessor
```